# Using a userinput as a variable in an If statement in BAT

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p a=Enter 1,2,3:
if %a%==1
 echo you entered 1
if %a%==2
 echo you entered 2
if %a%==3
 echo you entered 3
```

The conversion from a variabel that is a integer to a user input that is also an integer may require quotations but this is not the error that is preventing me from using this method in code. I've used this so many time it is embarrasing that i forgot how to do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire IF statement must reside on one line

```
@echo off
set /p a=Enter 1,2,3:
if %a%==1 echo you entered 1
if %a%==2 echo you entered 2
if %a%==3 echo you entered 3
```

unless you use parentheses

```
@echo off
set /p a=Enter 1,2,3:
if %a%==1 (
  echo you entered 1
)
if %a%==2 (
  echo you entered 2
)
if %a%==3 (
  echo you entered 3
)
```

or line continuation

```
@echo off
set /p a=Enter 1,2,3:
if %a%==1 ^
  echo you entered 1
if %a%==2 ^
  echo you entered 2
if %a%==3 ^
  echo you entered 3
```